# How to add a framework to a file in the "Sources" folder of Xcode Playground?

Tags: swift

I want to add my own framework to a swift file in the "Sources" folder in Swift Playground. I am able to add the framework to my Playground.

I am getting an error message of "No such module". The framework is in the same workspace as my Playground.

[image: The auxiliary source module did not compile successfully.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this by adding the framework in the "Resources" folder of the Playground. It works now!